# MacBook Pro's Trackpad not doing multi-touch gestures after sleep

Tags: macbook, touchpad

i've got a MacBook Pro mid 2012 with Mountain Lion.
Sometimes when i wake up my computer from sleep (open the laptop), all the multi touch gestures of the trackpad (4 fingers to change screen, 3 finger to move windows) don't work anymore. 
Tap to click, Two finger navigation still work

I don't understand why but it's not everytime so maybe i could just reload the driver or make it work again.
Is there a way to restart the trackpad service or should i really restart the computer completely to make it work again (it works but i don't want to restart it)

Thanks

EDIT : i have a Magic Mouse and the gesture of the Magic Mouse to change screen doesn't work anymore either. So it's maybe more a general problem than Trackpad.   Switching screen with Ctrl+Arrows works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Terminal
2. Type "killall Dock"
3. Press Enter on your keyboard

Problem solved.  At least temporarily.  The gestures will randomly stop working again, and when they do, repeat the above steps.